# Hibernate throws Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am working on a basic example to test `cascade delete` operation but I am getting exception.

I have below entities:

**Employee.java**

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMP_ID")
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
    private List<EmpDetails> details = new ArrayList<EmpDetails>();

}
```

**EmpDetails.java**

```
@Entity
public class EmpDetails {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private int info;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMP_ID")
    private Employee employee;
}
```

Now I have records in databse with employee id as 10 and corresponding records in employee details table.

Now when I run below query:

```
    session.beginTransaction();

    session.delete(new Employee(10)); // here 10 is the ID of the employee

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

I was thinking hibernate will delete the employee record and the corresponding employee details records as I have set the cascade type to remove. But I am getting exception as :

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Can someone please help me how to test the cascade delete option here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The REMOVE cascade type is for the standard JPA `remove()` operation. For the native Hibernate `delete()` operation, you need to use a [Hibernate-proprietary annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Cascade.html):

```
@Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE)
```

Comment: Hi JB, I have tried Delete option, but still getting same error. I am using hibernate annotations in my code for cascade related. My logs shows that it is not deleting from EmpDetails table but only from Employee table.

Comment: Another problem is that you're deleting `new Employee(10)`. This new Employee thus has no detail in its list. Use `delete(session.get(Employee.class, 10));`

Comment: Hi JB, can you please take a look at my post on Hibernate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37088759/get-employee-with-highest-salary-in-each-department

Comment: Hi @JBNizet The solution you mentioned in the comment (not in the answer) is working for me, however I cannot understand this part of your answer: "This new Employee thus has no detail in its list".  Can you please briefly explain the same.

Comment: Which Hibernate Version do you use? I just tried this with 5.3.1.Final but it doesn't delete the referenced items and fails because of the foreignKey constraint violation. My design has parent and child classes and the offending collection is from a parent that my child is extending on.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete Employee on session try to add this, I had the same issue:

```
session.delete(session.get(Employee.class, employee_Id));
```

On my issue I had Movie and TimeTable relation was OneToOne:

On Movie model:

```
public class Movie implements Serializable
{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "fid")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int fid;
   ....
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "movie", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private TimeTable timetable;
}
```

On TimeTable model:

```
public class TimeTable implements Serializable 
{
   ...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fid")
    private Movie movie;
}
```