# MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException for Hibernate hsql delete. Cannot delete or update a parent row

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have parent  `Filter` entity  and one direction `List<Ad>ads` as children with `@OneToMany`relation. I try delete ads where is more then one week old using Hibernate `hql` query but get:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`gecars`.`filters_ads`, CONSTRAINT `FK_gcri6h0918u8o2ybd6yfquk79` FOREIGN KEY (`ads_id`) REFERENCES `ads` (`id`))

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
 ...
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user") 
 @OrderBy("id")
 private Set<Filter> filters = new HashSet<Filter>(0);
 ...
```

Filter:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="filters")
public class Filter {
  ...
  // I also tried use @OneToMany(CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanremoval=true)
  // or @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
  @OneToMany 
  private Set<Ad> ads; 
  ...
```

Ad:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ads")
public class Ad {
 ...
 private Date insertTime = new Date();
 ...
```

DAO delete method:

```
public void deleteOldAds(Date date){
    String hql = "delete from Ad where insertTime < :date";
    session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("date",  date).executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Try cascade all there : @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

Comment: I tried it. Not working, get same Exception.

Comment: You can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146911/hibernate-throws-cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue is that a join table is used if `@OneToMany` association side is the owner of the relationship.

To specify that a join column (foreign key) in the `ads` table is used for the association instead of a separate join table, simply map the association with a `@JoinColumn`:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn 
private Set<Ad> ads;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is occurs because Hibernate will not delete entity `Ads` from relationship.

So you need to remove yourself `Ad` from relationship before delete.

Or you can use `@OneToMany` through `mappedBy` it will not create additional table `filters_ads` for relationship therefor will not create constrain.

Comment: So if I decide use @ManyToMany relation in my case, then i should first select All filters then foreach them and check ad insert time  and then remove it from ads list in Filter entity?

Comment: Something like this. But you can select only those Filters that have needed, that have Ad with time < :date.