# error with ManyToOne relations in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have 2 class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role",uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"role","username"}))
public class UserRole {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_role_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer userRoleId;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private User user;
    @Column(name = "role",nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String role;
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Column(name = "firstname", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = true)
    private String surName;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false, length = 60)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
    private boolean enabled;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<>(0);
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<AddressBook> addressBooks = new ArrayList<>(0);
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>(0);
```

When my app start at first time it create 3 tables:

**users_user_role** with columns *[users_username] [userrole_user_role_id]*;

**users** with columns *[username]  [email] [enabled] [firstname] [lastname] [password] [surname]*;

and

**user_role** with columns *[user_role_id] [role]   [username]*

When I save User with UserRole, I have a strange error:

```
2016-03-16 16:52:36.480 DEBUG 8280 --- [nio-8090-exec-9] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into users_user_role (users_username, user_role_user_role_id) values (?, ?)
2016-03-16 16:52:36.489 DEBUG 8280 --- [nio-8090-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : could not execute statement [n/a]

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "user_role_user_role_id" of relation "users_user_role" does not exist
```

Why it use the **user_role_user_role_id** if it created the **userrole_user_role_id** ?
How can I fix it?

Comment: Also, take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36012815/4754790).

Comment: May be it's some other. I want to change left-side of autogenerated column name, because it generate "user_role...", but in scripts it use "userrole..."

Answer (score 3):

Change `UserRole` mapping in `User` to

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private Set<UserRole> userRole = new HashSet<>(0);
```

`mappedBy` is necessary for Hibernate to know that this is the other side of bidirectional relationship.

Comment: If I do this, the hibernate don't create relations.

Comment: @NCNecros You don't need a join table for `@OneToMany`. You can have one, but it is generally not necessary. What you do need is a single join column in the dependent table (`user_role` in your case), and that is what you get with the mapping in my example. Check the database for `user_username` column in `user_role` table.