# Hibernate deleting parent with child for one to one mapping

Tags: hibernate

I have two table in database named Student(as parent) and StudentInfo (as child) and they have one to one relationship. When i delete Parent object then the related child object should be deleted.

my Student pojo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String studentName;

    @OneToOne(cascade= CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private StudentInfo info;
    // getters and setters 
}
```

and my StudentInfo pojo..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "studentInfo")
public class StudentInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "newGenerator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "newGenerator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "student"))
    private int id;
    private String mobileNo;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Student student;
    // getters and setters 
}
```

when i perform a delete operation on Student (parent) then only parent object is delete but child object id not deleted.How do i delete both parent and child?

Comment: Your mapping is incorrect. One of the side must be the inverse side, and thus use mappedBy. Also, Show how you delete a student.

Comment: this code for delete...
Student student1 = new Student();
student1.setId(7);
studentService.deleteStudent(student1);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(studentInfo);

Comment: Don't create a new Student to delete it. Get a reference to the persistence student using get() or load(). And read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146911/hibernate-throws-cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint/32148417#32148417