# @ManyToOne mapping with @JoinTable gets a foreign key constraint error

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a Response entity and every response can have only one user and every user can have many responses. I'm trying to connect it by a lookup table using @JoinTable in Response entity like this:

```
@ManyToOne()
@JoinTable(
        name = "response_user",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "response_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "firstName", "lastName", "email", "activated", "regDate", "lastVisit" })
private User user;
```

but I can't delete a user. I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`response_user`, CONSTRAINT `FKf48he1fef6q4d4t3kw4605pfw` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`))
```

What I would like to achieve is that when the user is deleted, it also deletes everything associated with that user.

Comment: you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32146911/hibernate-throws-cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint) question, same with your issue

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the error for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Response {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name="response_user",
               joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="response_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")})
    private User user;
}
```

Your User Entity should look like this:

```
public class User {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Response> responses;
}
```

Comment: do you know why the data that i get is all responses of all users?

Comment: The answer is related the question. I didn't understand why did you ask?