# Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I am still learning lot of things in hibernate and dealing with relationship between table in hibernate so in one of my project I am facing the following problem:

**what is the problem?**

I have a package class (which is an entity class)

```
@Entity
public class Package {
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  User sender;
  /*rest of class getter setter etc*/
}
```

I have have a User class (which is again an entity)

```
@Entity
public class User {
  @oneToOne
  Person person;
 /*rest of user class*/
}
@Entity class Person {
  /*email etc*/
}
```

**what I am trying to do?**

I am trying to delete the package entity without deleting the User referred in the package table

I am calling delete on the package entity through packageDAO

```
@Override
public void remove(E entity) {
    try {
        transaction = currentSession().beginTransaction();
        if (transaction == null) {
            throw new GenericDAOException(TRANS_NULL);
        }
        currentSession().delete(entity);
        transaction.commit();

    } catch (final HibernateException he) {
        if (transaction != null) {
            // Transaction has to be rolled back when exception is thrown
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        throw new GenericDAOException(he.getCause().toString());
    }
    currentSession().close();
}
```

**what error I am getting?**

exception.GenericDAOException:com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails    (`mydb`.`user_table`, CONSTRAINT `FK_o0l5sy9ohe6iy6fqutl68hc3l` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person_table` (`person_id`))

**what I have tried so far**

few of the solution that I tried match these post but I was not able to achieve the desired result, using `cascade.ALL, cascade.DELETE` would actually delete the user also while deleting the package which is not what I am looking for, few of the post that I referred already include:

[@OneToMany errors in MySQL: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629241/onetomany-errors-in-mysql-cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key)

[Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (hibernate xml mapping)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21852012/cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-a-foreign-key-constraint-fails-hibernate)

It would be great if any of you can through some light on hibernate on how can I delete one entity without deleting another entity in a @OneToOne mapped relationship

Comment: Check similar problem has been answered here:
[Cannot delete or update a parent row ConstraintViolationException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641181/cannot-delete-or-update-a-parent-row-constraintviolationexception/40645955#40645955)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is first remove the relationship of Package and User(set the fk of User in Package null).You can do this by setting the `sender` to null in Package entity and update it.Once you done that you can easily delete your Package entity without deleting the User entity.